# Javascript print code doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code, that's printing a specific div, when clicking on a link, but i cant seem to get it to work.

The purpose on the code is, when i click the link "HEJ" it's supposed to print my div, called mydiv, and i found a script that should do that, but i cant seem to get it to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function PrintElem(elem)
        {
            Popup($(elem).html());
        }

        function Popup(data) 
        {
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
            /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body><p style="font-family:arial">');
            mywindow.document.write(data);
            mywindow.document.write('</p></body></html>');

            mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
            mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();

            return true;
        }

    </script>
```

The above code is the javascript i found somewhere on the internet, and the code below is the HTML which triggers the javascript code.

```
<div id="mydiv">
Test
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="PrintElem('.mydiv')" />HEJ</a>
```

I've also tried to remove the . before mydiv in the onclick element, but none of it works, nothing happens when i click on the link.

I hope you guys can help me out, with this problem.

Comment: i havent fully gone through your code but can you try replacing the '.mydiv' with '#mydiv' and see if it works

Comment: Onfortunately it didn't work :)

Comment: please checkout @jedifans answer

Answer (score 4):

The argument being passed to `PrintElem()` is a jQuery selector, so `.mydiv` is selecting elements which have `class="mydiv"` on them.

In the above case as there is a div with an `id` of mydiv, let's target that instead, with `#mydiv`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="PrintElem('#mydiv')">HEJ</a>
```

I also fixed the self closing tag `/>` which would have not let your link work.

Answer (score 0):

Just got a call from a buddy, he said i should change the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script>
```

To

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.1.js" > </script>
```

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: please make sure you make this correction along with the answer provided by @jedifans

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you included the reference of JQuery into your code.

Put the jQuery reference into the head section and try again. Like

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!